# SQL query for subtracting values from columns and add it to same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sapb1

[image: or]

As you can see, the `Menge` column is decreasing its value for every row, subtracting the `Reserviert` value from the previous row.

Can anybody suggest how to write this type of query in SQL Server?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: You need to have a **proper** ordering criteria, so that you can establish the sequence of the rows - and then, depending on which **version** of SQL Server you're using, you might be able to use `LAG` command to handle this "new row's `Menge` is previous row's `Menge` minus the previous row's `Reserviert` value

Comment: i have used LAG() but its not happening. Actually it is the same field which is updating every time

Comment: Could you give some additional information?

Comment: @VyronPaschalidis What Kind of information Sir ??

Comment: Actually i want only the query how can write a query which gives me ("Menge"-"Reserviet ") result and it will be updated in the "Menge" automatically in the query itself

Comment: @SiddharthaDas Gordon Linoff has already given the answer but you need to tinker with it to have it exactly as you need. We won't write the query for you, you have the information needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Cannot be Done by SQL Only . It must to be done by Code

Answer (score 2):

You can use window functions -- in particular a cumulative sum.  It is not clear where the 200 is coming from, so I will hardcode it:

```
select t.*,
       (200 -
        sum(reservevert) over (partition by artikelnumber order by coalesce(lieferdatum, '2000-01-01')
       ) as merge          
from t;
```

Comment: As you can see in the image it's just the same field updating every time.